# Google Web App Only Logging When Accessed Via Browser

Tags: google-apps-script, post, cors

I have a weird problem with my Google web app:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("GET");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Thanks for using Apps Scripts</h1>');
}
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log("POST");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<h1>Thanks for using Apps Scripts</h1>');
}
```

The app is open, so everyone can access it.  When I paste the URL in a (private) window, it always works as expected, `doGet` is getting called and I see the log in the executions tab.  However, when I access the same URL via Fetch API in the browser console or some service like Postman or Klavio, I sometimes see no logs:

[image]

Some rows are just not expandable, hence not showing anything. To be more precise, Postman and Klavio post requests never worked, Fetch API requests work (both, GET and POST) when sent from the browser console in the same tab as the Apps Script page.  Could it be CORS-related?  But wouldn't I see an error then, instead of the completed status?  Postman requests also return status 200 and show no errors.

But it says that the function `doGet` was executed (and completed), and when I send a post request, it executes `doPost` as expected.  How can it execute my functions without logging anything?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, thanks for your comment!  My question is that some executions don't seem to have logs, which is weird, since the first thing which my `doGet` and `doPost` functions are doing is logging, so even if there is some CORS issue, I don't really understand why I see no errors and get the information that the functions successfully completed, yet I cannot see any logs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you access Web Apps with a browser by logging in to your Google account, the log can be recorded. But, when you access Web Apps with a script, curl command, postman, and so on, there is a rule for recording the log. In this case, I guessed that my report might be useful for understanding it. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script?tab=readme-ov-file#logs-in-web-apps-for-google-apps-script

Comment: Ah nice, thanks a lot!  What I'll try to do next is to modify some Google sheet instead of logging...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About `Ah nice, thanks a lot! What I'll try to do next is to modify some Google sheet instead of logging...`, your 1st question was resolved and you want to ask a new question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, not a new question, just announcing my plans what to do next!  Will come back to you if things fail or behave unexpected :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your 1st question was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Why aren't you posting it as an answer?  This way you would collect your deserved credit :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understand it. I will prepare an answer. Could you please wait for it?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't I wait for it :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted it as an answer by summarizing it. Please confirm it. If that is useful for you and other users, I'm glad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access Web Apps with a browser by logging in to your Google account, the log by `Logger.log` can be recorded. But, when you access Web Apps with a script, curl, postman, Javascript on the browser, and so on, it seems that there is a rule for recording the log by `Logger.log` and `console.log`. In this case, I think that [my report](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script?tab=readme-ov-file#logs-in-web-apps-for-google-apps-script) might be useful. I have never posted it on Stackoverflow. So, I would like to put it in this answer.

In order to test this, there are the following 3 steps.

#### 1. Sample script for Web Apps

This is a sample script for checking the log.

```js
const doGet = (e) => {
  Logger.log(`GET method: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
  console.log(`GET method: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    JSON.stringify({ method: "GET", e: e })
  );
};
const doPost = (e) => {
  Logger.log(`POST method: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
  console.log(`POST method: ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    JSON.stringify({ method: "POST", e: e })
  );
};
```

- This Web Apps is deployed as `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`.

#### 2. Sample Google Apps Script project

2 types of Google Apps Script projects are prepared in this test.

1. Google Apps Script of standalone type **WITHOUT** linking Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project

   - In this case, you can retrieve this standalone Google Apps Script by directly creating.
2. Google Apps Script of standalone type **WITH** linking Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project

   - In this case, you can retrieve this standalone Google Apps Script by [this flow](https://github.com/tanaikech/Linking-Google-Cloud-Platform-Project-to-Google-Apps-Script-Project-for-New-IDE).

#### 3. Test for `Logger.log` and `console.log`

To the above Web Apps of `doGet` and `doPost`, it requests the following 4 patterns.

1. For `doGet`.

   ```bash
   $ curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
   ```
2. For `doPost`.

   ```bash
   $ curl -L -d "key=value" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
   ```
3. For `doGet`. An access token is used.

   ```bash
   $ curl -L -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
   ```
4. For `doPost`. An access token is used.

   ```bash
   $ curl -L -H "Authorization: Bearer ###" -d "key=value" "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
   ```

### Result and discussions

The conditions that can confirm the logs are as follows.

|  | Without access token | With access token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Without linking GCP |  | Apps Script Dashboard |
| With linking GCP | Stackdriver | Apps Script Dashboard and Stackdriver |

From the above results, it was found as follows.

- When using a default Google Apps Script project without linking to Google Cloud Platform (GCP), accessing the Web Apps with an access token is necessary to retrieve requested logs, even if the deployment settings are `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`.
- When using a Google Apps Script project linked to GCP, you can retrieve all user access logs for the Web Apps from Stackdriver, regardless of deployment settings like `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone`.

#### References

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)