Google Apps Script not doing anything
I wrote a Google Apps Script to create a spreadsheet. While it worked perfectly when I ran it directly in the console, it didn't do anything when I ran it as a web app. So, in the interests of a minimum reproducible example, I removed all the actual code, so I can see what's going on:
function doPost(e) {
  console.log("testing");
  console.log(e);
  // buildSpreadsheet(e);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("test return");
}

If I run this in the console - by selecting doPost() & Run, it works, although it's not that exciting:
Execution log
10:03:08 AM Notice  Execution started
10:03:08 AM Info    testing
10:03:08 AM Info    undefined
10:03:09 AM Notice  Execution completed

And if I look in the executions tab, I can see this there too.
Head    doPost  Editor  May 14, 2024, 10:03:08 AM   0.429 s 
Completed
Cloud logs
May 14, 2024, 10:03:08 AM   Debug   testing
May 14, 2024, 10:03:08 AM   Debug   undefined

However, when I run the function from Make.com, it is executed, but it doesn't seem to do anything...  In the executions, the entry doesn't have a drop down like it does for the above where it succeeds:

The repsonse to the Make.com request is this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico">
  <title>Error</title>
  <style type="text/css" nonce="yj5brjSX8f6-1XbbgXItPA">
    body {
      background-color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .errorMessage {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12pt;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 150%;
      padding-top: 25px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin:20px">
  <div><img alt="Google Apps Script" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div>
  <div style="text-align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">The script completed but did not return anything.</div>
</body>

</html>



Editors Note:

The relevant content from the above HTML code is

The script completed but did not return anything.


Which also isn't much use! This is the first time I've used this, so apologies for not being able to get the hello world to work. Could an experienced user please advice what's going on?

There's a lot of things that  work differently when from ui for a real user and a webapp.  Personally I'd need to see the code.  The intended use of the doPost is to act as an endPoint for a url not to be called directly like anyother function.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, if my understanding is correct, I guess that this thread might be useful or related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78077503 But, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Hi all, I figured what I had was the most basic possible function. There is no code to show you! I basically post to the endpoint without any authorisation. @Tanaike I checked that link - sorry, but I don't know how to add a token or how to link the app to GCP. So, the web app will do nothing until I do one of those things??

Thank you for relpying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

@Tanaike You comment was useful. That information was very helpful.

May be i wrong, but it i think your problem is related to how to debug a doPost or doGet.
In those cases, console is not available for práctical purposes.
The solution I adopted in those cases is to log the information i need to... another sheet!
Just create another spreadsheet, grab its id and any sheet name and add to your code (the one where you are implemented the doPost) something like this:
function sheetLog_(sheet, dataArr) {

    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<<your-log-spreadsheet-id>>>/edit#gid=0
    const sp = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<<<your-log-spreadsheet-id>>>');
    const sh = sp.getSheetByName(sheet);
    const ahora = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT-3', 'YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');

    sh.appendRow([ahora].concat(dataArr));
    sh.sort(1, false);
}
function shLOG(dataArr) {
    sheetLog_('LOG', dataArr);
}
// -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
function sheetLog_test() { sheetLog_('LOG', ['Hola', 'Manola']); }

Replace <<<your-log-spreadsheet-id>>> with the id of the spreadsheet that you will use as your console loger.
Replace 'GMT-3' with your local time location.
Replace 'LOG' with the sheet name you choose into the spreadsheet you create to log.
sheetLog_(sheet, dataArr) will log in the sheet sheet all the members of dataArr each in one column and will put date and time in the first column.
Use shLog(dataArr) to log in a sheet named 'LOG'
Test your implementation with sheetLog_test()
To log something just call shLog, e.g.
shLOG(["testing", e]);

or better
shLOG(["testing", JSON.stringify(e, null, 4)]);

I hope I have interpreted your problem correctly.
